# ERROR: The conversion from bit to TIMESTAMP is unsupported

Tags: spring-boot

Estoy imprimiendo datos de mi base de datos que esta hecha en mysql el problema, cuando consulto un apartado de fecha me salta los siguientes errores

```
The conversion from bit to TIMESTAMP is unsupported.
 entrando a Excepcion
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
```

Pero solo es cuando necesito el dato de la fecha,los demas datos se muestran bien

muestro el controlador

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/busEgre", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String buscarEgresado(@RequestParam("id") int clave, Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  {
        System.out.println(clave);
        Egresado egresa=egresadoPlusService.getUsuario(clave);
        model.addAttribute("egresado", egresa);
        System.out.println("exito: "+egresa.getId());
        return "Egresados/ediEgresados";
    }
```

muestro donde se hace la consulta

```
    @Query("SELECT e FROM Egresado e WHERE e.id= :clave")
    Egresado getUsuario(@Param("clave") int clave);
```

---

Asi es mi entidad en java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="catEgresados")
public class Egresado {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="IDEgresado")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NoCuenta") 
    private String noCuenta;

    @Column(name = "Paterno")
    private String paterno;

    @Column(name = "Materno")
    private String materno;

    @Column(name = "Nombres")
    private String nombres;

    @Column(name="Osexo")
    private String sexo;

    @Column(name="FechaNac")
    private Date fechaNac;

    @Column(name="Procedencia")
    private Date procedencia;

    @Column(name="CURP")
    private Date curp;

    @Column(name="RFC")
    private Date rfc;
```

y en mi base de datos de encuentan asi

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zQDN.png

Comment: Podrias compartir los campos de la entidad `Egresado` e informacion acerca de las columnas de la tabla `Egresado`? Suena a que la columan de la BD no coincide con el tipo de la columna de la entidad de Java.